# PnL calculation on R/Quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I am very new to R as well as to this community, hope all of you are doing well.
I am trying to make a shortcut calculating PnL for 2-3 stocks; say if I use getQuote() to extract the last traded price. From here, may I ask how do I insert my entry price, so I can get subtract the last traded price with my entry price to get the PnL?

I think I need to insert my entry price somehow, and compare entry price to column 3 on the attached result?

Update:

Right now I have the below codes, if I ask, if I wanna subtract last done price to my entry price, how should I code it out?

Again. Thanks a lot.[SOXL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIiDa.png)

Anyway, many thanks for helping. Any thoughts are well appreciated.

[getQuote("SOXL")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCOga.png)